# Python cut list by a certain word

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
[["tab1", None], ["val1", 10], ["val2", "test"], ["val3", 20], ["tab2", None], ["val4", "test"], ["val5", 30]]
```

and i am searching for a method that cut in n lists if the word "tab" is found, the result could be this:

```
list1 = [["val1", 10], ["val2", "test"], ["val3", 20]]

list2 = [["val4", "test"], ["val5", 30]]
```

I try with some for cycle but nothing done.

but i don't have idea how this is possible with python.
Someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will there always be just two `"tab"` in your list?

Answer (score 8):

I would favour a simple `for` loop for this:

```
In [56]: new_l = []

In [57]: for i in l:
    ...:     if 'tab' in i[0]:
    ...:         new_l.append([])
    ...:     else:
    ...:         new_l[-1].append(i)
    ...:          

In [58]: new_l
Out[58]: 
[[['val1', 10], ['val2', 'test'], ['val3', 20]],
 [['val4', 'test'], ['val5', 30]]]
```

There's probably a shorter solution, but I doubt it'd be a better one.

Edit: Found a shorter version with `itertools.groupby` (still prefer the loop though):

```
In [66]: [list(v) for _, v in filter(lambda x: x[0], itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x: 'tab' not in x[0] ))]    
Out[66]: 
[[['val1', 10], ['val2', 'test'], ['val3', 20]],
 [['val4', 'test'], ['val5', 30]]]
```

Comment: Would appreciate knowing why the downvote. Would like the opportunity to fix any mistakes

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but maybe you should change the `if` and include `any`, just for security if `tab` is in the other index.

Comment: @RompePC I don't think so, it seems tab is always at index 0 (will change if OP clarifies).

Comment: Thanks for for loop solution

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pythonic way using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [10]: from itertools import groupby

In [12]: delimiters = {'tab1', 'tab2'}

In [13]: [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, delimiters.intersection) if not k]
Out[13]: 
[[['val1', 10], ['val2', 'test'], ['val3', 20]],
 [['val4', 'test'], ['val5', 30]]]
```

A more general approach that doesn't require specifying the delimiters, is using a lambda function as the `groupby`'s key function (but with less performance):

```
In [14]: [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0].startswith('tab')) if not k]
Out[14]: 
[[['val1', 10], ['val2', 'test'], ['val3', 20]],
 [['val4', 'test'], ['val5', 30]]]
```

Comment: Gorgeous.  I was just starting to fiddle with itertools to find something pythonic when  you beat me to it.

Comment: Nice. Didn't want to give you the wrong idea, so just letting you know I found my groupby solution independent of yours :) (yours is nicer though)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No problem ;)